# Is the meaning of "find" in the phrase "How did you find it" related to the meaning of "find" in other contexts?

Tags: meaning, etymology, phrases, semantics, metaphors

Compare the following:

- How did you find the restaurant? It was excellent. I enjoyed my meal.
- How did you find the restaurant? I looked it up in a street directory.

Asking, "How did you find [something]" to query someone's opinion or experience doesn't seem to relate directly "find" in the context of locating something. Even as a metaphor, referring to the act of locating something rarely includes a description of the thing itself. Are the two uses homonymic then? Or polysemic? Why this wording? Is there some history to the phrase or word that can clarify?

Comment: Hello and welcome! I've added a couple of examples so that the difference you're describing is immediately obvious. Please feel free to [edit] further or to [roll back](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/393345/revisions) the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [OED](http://www.oed.com) has, as the primary meaning of "find" (going back to Old English): " I. To come upon by chance or in the course of events."

Sense 4b (also found in Old English) is given as: "With object and complement or infinitive. To discover or perceive (something) to be in a specified state or condition."

This later develops [1545] into Sense 5b: "In a more subjective sense: to feel to be (agreeable, disagreeable, etc.), to consider or regard as (ridiculous, excellent, etc.)."

So the first sense of "find" noted in the question, an act of estimation, is a direct development, first occurring in the mid-sixteenth century, of a word originally found [!] in Old English, and referring to an act of locating -- the second sense in the question.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth  Oops!  I accidentally deleted your Edit without meaning to!  Please reinstate it.  Apologies.  RH

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Exactly.  Your Edit was quite correct, and I hadn't intended to reverse it.  (I'm still coming to terms with the input conventions on this forum, and thick-fingered in this instance.)

Comment: Actually, the "[!]" should probably be removed as well.  Intrusive and unnecessary on my part.